# VBA Access - Run Time Error 91 (but not for all)

Tags: vba, ms-access, jspdf

I have stumbled upon a weird problem where the VBA module for Microsoft Access is running perfectly fine on my computer, but whenever a colleague of mine tries to execute the code he receives the following error message: "Run-time error 91: Object variable not set". I am really confused why the exact same code can be executable on one machine and not on the other. Therefore, would be really grateful if you can maybe suggest what might be causing this weird behaviour. Thank you in advance.

This is part of the code that is connected to the error:

```
Dim AcroApp As Acrobat.CAcroApp
Dim AcroForm As Acrobat.CAcroPDDoc
Dim fetchJs As Object

Set AcroApp = CreateObject("AcroExch.App")
Set AcroForm = CreateObject("AcroExch.PDDoc")

AcroForm.Open "Path to a file location"

Set fetchJs= AcroForm.GetJSObject

Forms![form_name]![field_name].value = fetchJs.getField("pdf_input_id").value 'On this line the code breaks
```

A few things that may or may not be useful:

- The access file is stored on a mutual drive that we both have access to and we both run the file from that location instead of saving it on our personal drives.
- We run different languages on both computers, but when I changed my computer language to his (after restart) the code was still running on my end.
- All needed reference libraries are checked when he opens the access file from his computer.
- The script is running from a button located at the same form where we want to save the fetched information. Therefore, it will not return an error that the field cannot be found.

Comment: Which line is throwing the error?

Comment: @NicholasHunter, the last line, per comment in code.

Comment: Form and field are actually named `form_name` and `field_name`? If code is behind `form_name`, then use `Me!field_name`.

Comment: Check very carefully that you don't have `On Error Resume Next` in your code. `fetchJs` is probably still `Nothing` when the last line runs.

Comment: Is "Path to a file location" a UNC or does it contain a drive mapping?

Comment: Set a break point on the line that is throwing the error and check the values of `Forms![form_name]![field_name]` and `fetchJs.getField("pdf_input_id")`

Comment: Also you should probably change `Forms![form_name]![field_name] = ...` to `Forms![form_name]![field_name].Value = ...`

Comment: @June7, No, the `form_name` and `field_name` are just for example purposes. In addition, the code is not behind the form that is why I thought it was needed to also reference the full full name before the field name.

Comment: @Andre, This actually might be a promising lead to look further into, as indeed the function has a build `On Error Resume Next` part.

Comment: So, I am confused by "**script is running from a button located at the same form where we want to save the fetched information**".

Comment: @June7, Sorry, maybe I haven't explained it correctly. The form has a button that has an on-click event that calls a function that is saved in a module inside the same access file.

Comment: @Andre, Slightly off-topic question, but another reason that came into my mind was an issue with the reference paths. For example, if a reference library is added by me and the path location was set `C:\Users\John\.....` does that mean that if another user tries to run the code, even dough when you go to references the library will be checked, Access wouldn't be able to pull the necessary library as now there is no `John` user folder on his computer? I am not sure if Access is storing the library internally once it has been added or it is being pulled every single time when the code is run.

Comment: Then yes, full form path reference needed. Have you step debugged as suggested above? I don't see `On Error Resume Next` line. If code won't compile then it surely can't run correctly. Why would you have that line? I expect the reference library path would be an issue.

Comment: @June7, To be completely honest, before Andre mentioned `On Error Resume Next` for some reason it never came into my mind that the problem might be coming from somewhere else and breaking on this line as it is just after the `On Error Resume Next` function. I have commented this part out and tomorrow I will let my colleague to rerun the function again and see if the error will break on the same line or on another. In addition, I will check the reference library paths, because today I just checked if the libraries were ticked or not. (Will post a comment of what I found.)

Comment: @NicholasHunter Thank you for the suggestion. I will definitely check the two separately, but my gut tells me that the problem is coming from `fetchJs`. In regard to your second comment, I think as I had to type everything manual I just missed to add the `.value` at the end. Please excuse me for that. I have already edited my post. Last but not least, the location of the file is using drive mapping, with a few bits that are auto generated in order to take it from the correct sub-folder. That said we both have the same letter in the mutual drive that we use.

Comment: If you have `On Error Resume Next` then it's possible the "problem" users have "Break on all errors" set as the option for error handling ("Break in class module" would be preferrable)